# how can I iterate through all keys with python and leveldb

Tags: python, leveldb, database, nosql

I want to use python's leveldb bindings to store data.  I don't see in any of the docs how to iterate through all the keys without knowing them ahead of time.  I see it is possible in the C bindings from this page:
https://rawgit.com/google/leveldb/master/doc/index.html

```
leveldb::Iterator* it = db->NewIterator(leveldb::ReadOptions());
for (it->SeekToFirst(); it->Valid(); it->Next()) {
  cout << it->key().ToString() << ": "  << it->value().ToString() << endl;
}
assert(it->status().ok());  // Check for any errors found during the scan
delete it;
```

How can I do this from within python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using [Plyvel](https://github.com/wbolster/plyvel), you can simply do `for key, value in db:` as per [the docs](http://plyvel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user.html#iterators).

Comment: i had just found that and tried to answer my own question, but you beat me to it :)